# user flow using a feedback button

Tags: mobile, buttons, feedback, user-feedback

Suppose I have a mobile app which asks users for their feedback on the app.
The feedback button is located on the main screen at the bottom of the list (the app is built with a list).

After the user had already given his feedback, should I

1. Continue and present the feedback button on the main screen?
2. Move the button to other less frequently visited pages?
3. Show the current feedback status of the app (assuming its positive)?

Any other options ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I propose a little different feedback model:

1. **Don't display feedback** for a reasonable time or number of runs. Let the user get acknowledged with your app first and forms his opinion. Otherwise user could give fast "false" feedback for just get rid of annoying button or just ignore it (like banner blindness effect).
2. **Display feedback** for reasonable time then. If user after some app usage ignores the feedback again, it means he doesn't want to give a feedback. So don't bother him, move feedback away to...
3. ... **Move feedback button to `About` dialog** or some contact screen, i.e. the place, where a user probably hopes to find it if he will decide to contact with you.

And a trick which could help you to get feedback at the **Display feedback** phase. Besides just displaying feedback button, place in the feedback block current app raiting (stars, points, marks, etc.). It is the social proof of others leave feedback and it could stimulate the user to leave feedback, too.

Here not only social proof works. The current app rating could create some emotion, like *"How could they give it 5? It's wrong! I faced errors here and there! Now I leave the true feedback!"* or *"I agree with theirs mark! I support them by leaving feedback"*.